# AppScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'snippet' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube, spreadsheet

I am trying to do something that I'm not sure if is right. **I wanna get YouTube channels categories using YouTube API and output it in a Google Spreadsheet (I'm coding in AppScript) through YouTube channel IDs**. I find a way through "Guide Categories" on the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list?hl=pt-br).

```
    function googleC() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    var id = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
    var request = YouTube.GuideCategories.list('snippet',{id:'UClkieE3BBB4xXoMvBj7_TRw'}).items[0].snippet.channelId;


    sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(request);
}
```

The error I'm recieving is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'snippet' of undefined (line 5,"Code")**. Is that any way to fix it?

Comment: it means `items` is empty `[]`

Comment: The response is not returning any `item`. What does the specified `id` refer to?

Comment: It refers to the YouTube Channel ID, is the same ID specified on {id:'UClkieE3BBB4xXoMvBj7_TRw'}.

Comment: When you use ["GuideCategories: list"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list), it seems that `id` is category ID. The official document says `The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube channel category ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a guideCategory resource, the id property specifies the YouTube channel category ID.`